# In-App Billing subscription issues

Tags: google-play

With the release of the new subscription option from In-App Billing API we started a proof of concept of the service and we found a few issues. Has anyone else tried it and would have some answers for us? Here's the issues we have been facing so far:

1 – While testing the unsubscribe functionality, the Google Play interface displays a white page with an “Item not found” message and a retry button. Is it due to the fact the app is not yet published? If yes, how can we test this flow without publishing it first?

2 – Inter device synchronization. When making a subscription on one device, other devices tied to the same account did not receive a OnPurchaseStateChange event. Is it again due to the fact the app is not published? Or are subscriptions tied to a particular device and not to an account?

3 – On our Google merchant page, when we cancel a purchase, the device does not receive a notification telling the subscription has been cancelled. Is this a bug? As a workaround we are manually checking the current time and comparing with the expiration date to force a restore transactions call. At this point, we are able to see the subscription is no longer valid. Do you think this is an acceptable solution?

4 – When a subscription is made, two transactions show up on the Google Merchant page: a FAILED transaction with a value of $0 and a valid one with the value we charged. Is this the expected behavior? What’s the purpose of the $0 FAILED transaction?

If anyone has faced similar issues we would like to know. Maybe these could be bugs on Google's end or maybe we did not understand 100% how it is supposed to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any more information/knowledge on the mechanism of subscription cancellation? Specifically, how do we know the expiry date without having to restore transactions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.I had the same issue and after I published (and later unpublished) my app I could see the app page in the market,so you can publish and than unpublish.

2.I didn't check it with subscriptions ,but for managed item i didn't get purchaseStateChange on two different devices as expected.

3.I do get subscription expired after canceling one,but only after a while.
I didn't understood how you can get the expiration date ? 
you only can get it with access to play developer api.
the restore transactions will give you same purchaseStateChange as you got when purchase the item.
*in the developer guide it is recommanded to use restore transactions only in first app use.

4.I have same issue,and i heard at least about 10 people with same 0$ charge.